# How can I log(watchdog)?

Tags: 8, log-messages, symfony-services

In D7 is used to log using Watchdog function. In D8, I see its gone and I should use something called the [logging API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/logging-api/overview).

What I a trying to do:

1. I have created a menu/route, `mysite.com/logmessage`
2. When user opens that url in browser, I want to log "hello" to the dblog.

Where should I register the service that D8 documentation says to do? Is it in the services.yml file in `sites/default` folder?

Can I just load the said class in my controller/module file and call the function for logging? Or should I explicitly extend the class first in my module before using the function?

Comment: see change record [ControllerBase now has a logger method](https://www.drupal.org/node/2623682)

Comment: I used the above code and flushed the cache. Even after that i am not getting anything in dblog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I just load the said class in my controller/module file and call the function for logging?

Yes; well, by "load the said class" you actually mean "get or inject an instance of the service class" in this context, but yes.

> should I explicitly extend the class first in my module before using the function?

Not unless you need functionality that the existing service doesn't provide.

In non DI code use:

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->info('Info');
```

In DI code, inject the service and use:

```
$this->logger->info('Info');
```

Comment: DI:
you either inject it via service file OR using the ContainerInjectionInterface and listing the services in the class in the create method

Comment: Yep @ssibal, or it's already available if you're in a controller

Comment: I don't really like the base drupal controller, but it's a different topic!: )

Comment: You either extend ControllerBase or create your own from the ground up. For many people the first one will suffice most of the time.

Comment: For different types for log message like 'info' or 'alert' refer this link http://www.tamildic.com/how-to-log-watchdog-message-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 4):

There are many different types of logging, all called the same way as [per the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21psr%21log%21Psr%21Log%21LoggerInterface.php/interface/LoggerInterface/8.5.x):

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->alert($message);

\Drupal::logger('my_module')->info($message);

\Drupal::logger('my_module')->debug($message);
```

Just call this code anywhere in your module, if you want to register `logmessage` as a path you'll need to create `my_module.routing.yml`, etc.